# Преобразование int в long

Tags: java

```
static void l(long l){
    System.out.println("l" + l);
}

static void i(int i){
    System.out.println("i  = " + i);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    i(1000000000*9);

}
```

Почему результат будет таков

> i  = 410065408

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему просто происходит переполнение. int в java имеет размерность 4 байта, и его максимальное значение равно 2 147 483 647, что явно меньше, чем 1000000000*9 (9 миллиардов).

Но прикол тут в том, что ваше число представлено как произведение двух чисел, каждое из которых умещается в рамках int. Будь у вас написано просто 9000000000, вы бы просто получили ошибку компиляции. Я не знаток java, и меня тут несколько удивляет, почему java не высчитывает это произведение в compile-time  (а это константа времени компиляции), благодаря чему можно было бы понять, что число в рамки int не влезет и выдать ошибку компиляции, что уберегло бы от такой неочевидной проблемы

Comment: Вот меня интересует, почему именно такой результат.

Comment: @romashechka, 9000000000 > Integer.MAX
Всего Integer вмещает 2^32 = 4294967296 значений.  
9000000000 > 4294967296 - значит 9 миллиардов содержат значения, которые будут отброшены (при переполнении происходит переход с верхней границы допустимых значений на нижнюю). Вычтем один раз количество элементов, которые может содержать данный тип: 9000000000 - 4294967296 = 4705032704 - это значение все еще больше максимального количества элементов. Вычтем еще раз: 4705032704 - 4294967296 = 410065408.

Comment: спасибо, все ясно

Comment: @romashechka, пожалуйста, но забудьте то, что я показал, ибо отбросить лишние значения можно было бы гораздо проще, но мб для тех, кто не шибко дружит с математикой - менее нагляднее.

Comment: @romashechka, кстати, это еще так получилось, что после переполнения осталось положительное значение... ))

Comment: @dreamchild Java таки вычисляет произведение литералов во время компиляции, это можно увидеть запустив `javap -c -v ClassName` и посмотрев на то, что находится в Constant pool. Проверки переполнения тут нет, видимо, для того, чтобы сохранить поведение такого же вычисления в рантайме. Полагаю, что C/С++ компиляторы делают точно так же и Java унаследовала такое поведение у них.